# How to populate C# list and perform multiplication between items in the list and some value riched by SQL procedure

Tags: c#, list, matrix, multiplication

I would ask for some help related my problem.

I need to calculate in C# according to formula :

(Ra,p -RavgA)
Where :

1. Ra,p is "rating of user a for item p" and
2. RavgA is "user's average rating"

To reach data "rating of users a for item p" I'm using SQL stored procedure:

```
SELECT     Ocjena_ID
```

FROM         OcjeneKorisnika
WHERE     (Korisnik_ID = @Korisnik_ID)

For example, this stored procedure give me values for "Ocjena_ID" :

1. 4
2. 5
3. 5

To populate list in C#, in DBBL I have defined :

```
public List<SelectOcjeneZaDoSadaOcjenjeneArtikleSP_Result> SelectOcjeneZaDoSadaOcjenjeneArtikleSP(int Korisnik_ID)
    {
        return context.SelectOcjeneZaDoSadaOcjenjeneArtikleSP(Korisnik_ID).ToList();

    }
```

For calculation of "user's average rating", I'm using in CB :

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=OnLineTeaShop;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.AVG_Evaluation_for_CustomerV2SP"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Korisnik_ID", Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"])));

                    SqlParameter countParameter = new SqlParameter("@retAVGVal", SqlDbType.Float);
                    countParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(countParameter);

                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string SrednjaVrijednost = cmd.Parameters["@retAVGVal"].Value.ToString();


                    txtAktvniAVG.Text = SrednjaVrijednost;


                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
```

This code give me in txtAktivniAVG field value 4,67.

Question is how to reach data from the list in CB file and calculate multiplication for each items in list with value reached for "user's average rating", and create/populate matrix which need to have 1 row and i ( in this case 3) columns with those data ?

Thank you in advance on support.

BR,

Damir

Comment: if I understood correctly: cant u return a Tuple<int, decimal> from List<SelectOcjeneZaDoSadaOcjenjeneArtikleSP_Result> method. Then you can then do then AVG in that method itself.

Comment: Not exactly, I can reach data from DB with my procedure ( for list and AVG ). If apply Listview I can see values, but don't know how to perform mathematical operation to multiplication values from list and value reached by stored procedure for AVG and write it in matrix.